# Powershell restrict Remote access on Host

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have three windows 2008 R2 servers; DEV, UAT and Live.  I am deploying web apps between these servers, including IIS setup and config and database backup and restore via a PowerShell script.  I use a powershell remote session.
I would like to prevent any machine, other than my deployment machine, from creating a powershell remote session on the host, even if the user is authenticated.  Is this possible?

I have looked extensively through the PSRemoting documentation and can't find anything helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use certificate-based authentication.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wmi/archive/2009/03/23/how-to-use-wsman-config-provider-for-certificate-authentication.aspx

If you only want your computer to be able to connect, install the certificate on your computer and don't give it to anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

Read the below link to better understand what needs to be done but I think you need to set the trusted host on the remote servers.

http://blogs.dirteam.com/blogs/sanderberkouwer/archive/2008/02/23/remotely-managing-your-server-core-using-winrm-and-winrs.aspx

This is an excerp from the blog.

**On the Windows server Core box**

> Run the following commands on the console of the Server Core box to lower security:

```
WinRM set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}
WinRM set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="<local>"} 
WinRM set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="RemoteHost"}
```

Where **RemoteHost** is the host you want to be able to connect to the server.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the reply. Trustedhosts are used to prevent you from connecting to malicious machines and passing your credentials, not from preventing malicious clients from connecting to you.  http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/7257.aspx#windows-powershell-remoting-technologies